# Как обобщить классы-детей? Python ООП

Tags: python, ооп, наследование, типизация

Предположим ситуацию:

```
class Weapon:
    pass

class Rifle(Weapon):
    magic = None

class Pistol(Weapon):
    pass

class MachineGun(Weapon):
    pass
```

А также предположим ситуацию, что есть функция, возвращающая случайное оружие, оружие которое наследуется от класса Weapon

```
def GetRandomWeapon() -> Rifle | Pistol | MachineGun:
    pass
```

Можно ли эту запись сократить (" -> Rifle | Pistol | MachineGun:"), чтобы при добавление новых классов наследников при обращение к полям именно наследников не вызывало ошибок (Нууу, не совсем ошибок, а чтобы в ide красным не горело, и подсказки были )
т.е.

```
gun = GetRandomWeapon()
gun.Magic = 4 # Поле, свойственное только Rifle
```

Надеюсь, я более менее понятно объяснил

Comment: А если из GetRandomWeapon() выпадет Pistol, у которого нет magic, то что должно произойти на строчке ``gun.Magic = 4``?

Comment: Делать проверку, что это именно объект класса с этим полем, потом только обращаться к этому полю.

Comment: Как обобщать - так и указывайте общий родительский класс: `def GetRandomWeapon() -> Weapon:`